Checks in Odoo 17
My country's fiscal position has few things configured in Odoo. For example, it does not have any format for checks. I want to create my own format with xml, but I don't know how I should upload it to odoo.
<odoo>
  <data>
    <report
      id="report_swift_solutions_check"
      string="Cheque personalizado por Swift Solutions, S.A."
      model="account.payment"
      report_type="qweb-pdf"
      name="swift_cheques.custom_swift_solutions_check"
      file="swift_cheques.custom_swift_solutions_check"
      print_report_name="prueba"
    />
  </data>
</odoo>

I found this little reference on how to upload it to Odoo but I can't find my report, it's like nothing is uploaded.
